# Spark read function not working in Intellij. Beginner in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I am using Intellij ide with java version 11.

The dependencies which I am using are -

1. Oracle JDK 11
2. apache.spark.core_2.12:3.3.0
3. apache.spark.sql_2.12:3.3.0
4. apache.spark.streaming_2.13:3.3.0

This is how I am adding dependencies in my project using maven -

[Adding Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Cy9.jpg)

My code looks like this -

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;

public class DatasetAPI {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Temp").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("location/data.json");
        df.show();
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is in this line -

```
 Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("location/data.json");
```

It says - Cannot resolve symbol 'spark'

I have tried looking for the various dependencies of spark and adding them to my project but I am not able to find which dependencies I am missing here.

Comment: This is because spark is a variable that you are missing, not because of dependencies.  For example you need to do something similar to ` SparkSession spark =
                SparkSession.builder().appName("Log Analyzer").getOrCreate();` then use spark variable